# Jquery, remove all handlers from a custom event

Tags: jquery

NB This is a custom event, not one attached to an object

Given an event like the below

```
$.event.trigger({
            type: "PopupInitialised",
        });
```

How could I remove -all- events attached to it?

Also, $.event isn't a good googleable search term, where could I find some documentation on using it?

Thanks

Comment: After trying a few combinations the below seemed to work,  is $.event deprecated perhaps?

$(document).off('PopupInitialised')

Comment: Is there a reason you are not triggering the event on an object in the DOM? [$.event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L35) is not part of the public api for jQuery and may change in future versions.

Comment: I didn't realize it wasn't :-( What I want is an event I can fire to tell parts of the page to update themselves. It will be fired as the result of an ajax call, not due to a click or anything else.

Comment: Typical site detailing use of this, but I found this off a different site

http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/

Comment: You can use `$(document).on("Foo", someFunction);`,  `$(document).trigger("Foo");` and `$(document).off("Foo");` in that case. As long as everything listens on the same element it will work. Take a look at the [events namespacing](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) documentation too.

Comment: Great thanks for that. It answers the question but given that these are comments I'm never sure what to do about marking as an answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer to match your question more closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to avoid using `$.event` as [it is part of jQuery's internals and may change later](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L35).

It would be easier to use the normal `.on(` and `.off(` handlers. eg:

```
$(document).on("Foo", someFunction);
$(document).trigger("Foo");
$(document).off("Foo");
```

As long as everything listens on the same element (ie the document) it will work.

Take a look at the [events namespacing](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) documentation too to make it easier to remove only the event handlers you mean to remove.